# How to hide or remove a existing Smart Tag for a user control?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

### SCENARIO

---

I have this control that inherits from ComboBox, and it displays this Smart Tag "**Edit Items...**":

[image]

What I would like to do is remove that command from my control to avoid the user from editting the Items collection of that control.

By the moment I just hide the Items property in the source-code:

C# version:

```
public class DriveComboBox : ImageComboBox { // ImageComboBox inherits from ComboBox

    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [MergableProperty(false)]
    [Bindable(false)]
    public new ImageComboBoxItemCollection Items {
        get { return base.Items; }
    }
}
```

VB.NET version:

```
Public Class DriveComboBox : Inherits ImageComboBox ' ImageComboBox inherits from ComboBox

    <Browsable(False)>
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
    <MergableProperty(False)>
    <Bindable(False)>
    Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Items As ImageComboBoxItemCollection
        Get
            Return MyBase.Items
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

...I'm aware it can be accessed anyways typying the member name, however at least it is hidden from the common user.

### QUESTION

---

How can I hide/remove the "**Edit Items...**" Smart Taf for my control?.

And optionaly please if someone could remember me the url to the MSDN article that explained how to add new commands/tasks to that menu...

**EDIT:** Not necessary, @**Plutonix** already answered to my optional petition.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz359sc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Plutonix Great! was that name "Smart Tags". Thanks for remembering me it. Any ideas how I could hide a existing smart tag for a inherited ComboBox? maybe I will need to do it through reflection?...

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just decorate the class with `<System.ComponentModel.Designer(GetType(System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner))> ` to eliminate the smart-tag completely.  If not, you will need a custom designer class and a custom DesignerActionList .

Comment: @TnTinMn That is like magic. It solved the problem. Thankyou!